# How to pass value from json to php

Tags: json

1.php script

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: true
            }
        });

        $.getJSON('php2.php?ID' + Id, function (json) {
            $('#container').highcharts({

                chart: {
                    type: 'spline',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'EMG'
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'

                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'EMG'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false,
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'TOP',
                    x: 50,
                    y: 35,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    line: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'EMG',
                    data: json.data,
                    datataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        rotation: -90,
                        color: '#FFFFFF',
                        align: 'right',
                        y: 10,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '13px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black',

                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
        });
    })
});
```

2.php

```
<?php
$Id =$_GET['ID'];
error_reporting(0);
$con = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
    echo "not connected";
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
$SQL1 = "SELECT  DateandTime,EMG FROM sensor_table WHERE ID='".$Id."'";
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'EMG';
$result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $rows['data'][] = [$r['DateandTime'],$r['EMG']];

}
json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This is my code ..i cant find my error .. the values can't to retrieve in php 2  please help me

Comment: `$.getJSON` is a Javascript function, not PHP.[

Comment: yeah .. just calling from one php to another php... one php have script another php have my query how to pass my value @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is a jQuery function used from Javascript, not PHP. You should do:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://localhost/2.php?ID=" . $Id));
```

In Javascript you use `+` to concatenate variables.

```
$.getJSON('2.php?ID=' + <?php echo $Id; ?>, function(json) {
    ...
});
```

In `2.php` you're not echoing the result. You need to do:

```
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: https://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/how-to-generate-json-with-php-from-mysql-and-parse-it-with-jquery/ this is similar code just i want to pass my value with **where** condition.. i just use my java script @Barmar

Comment: I've added a Javascript version.

Comment: I tried something different. Your question isn't very clear about where these variables are coming from.

Comment: You can't use PHP in jsfiddle.

Comment: I put it in the question where it belongs.

Comment: You forgot to echo the JSON in `2.php`.

Comment: thanks .... i think have problem in $Id =$_GET['ID']; and $.getJSON('php2.php?ID' + Id, function (json)  @Barmar

Comment: i correct my error .. still i have same problem @Barmar

Comment: You're missing the `=` after `?ID`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir ... thank you for spending your time with me ... i got my answer @Barmar